# \includegraphics tex4ebook conversion working on ReadEra but not Mac Books.app?

Tags: includegraphics, tex4ebook

Below is a MWE that renders text and an image of two circles and line:

```
\documentclass[ebook]{memoir}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./images/ebook} }

\begin{document}
Here's a png:\\
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{chapter_ornament.jpg}
\end{document}
```

[image]

After I convert with `tex4ebook main.tex` the image looks great on ReadEra but is broken on Mac Book.app:

[image]

Below is the generated HTML. I know eReaders vary, but Book.app can load images with other books. How do I get it to load my images?

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd"><html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'> 
<head><title></title> 
<meta content='text/html; charset=utf-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' /> 
<meta content='TeX4ht (https://tug.org/tex4ht/)' name='generator' /> 
<meta content='TeX4ht (https://tug.org/tex4ht/)' name='originator' /> 
<!--  xhtml,charset=utf-8,epub,uni-html4,html  --> 
<meta content='main.tex' name='src' /> 
<link href='main.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' /> 
</head><body>
<!-- l. 6 --><p class='noindent'>Here’s a png:<br class='newline' /><img alt='PIC' height='289' src='./images/ebook/chapter_ornament.jpg' width='289' />
</p>      
</body></html>
```

Comment: It seems like a `Book.app` bug? The file path seems to be OK. Try to use  `\graphicspath{ {images/ebook/} }` command instead, maybe it has problem with the trailing `./`.

Comment: @michal.h21 That was it! Thanks!

Comment: great! I will add a proper answer later.

Comment: Perfect! FYI, I found the trailing slash in `images/ebook/` created paths like `images/ebook//myimage.png` so I dropped the trailing slash.

Comment: Yes, I found that too, it produces `epubcheck` error when you use trailing slash.

Comment: It's simply offended that your document says "Here's a PNG" but then instead of a PNG, it provides a JPEG.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be caused by your `\graphicspath` command. When you use it in this way, the Graphics package constructs this image name:

```
./images/ebook//chapter_ornament.jpg
```

It seems that some Ebook readers don't support this form - both leading `./` and double slash seems to be a problem. It can be fixed easily, fortunately. Just use this graphics path:

```
 \graphicspath{ {images/ebook} }
```

It produces this file:

```
 images/ebook//chapter_ornament.jpg
```

which seems to work correctly

Comment: @BenVoigt you are right, my bad